# VSTS Load Test Report display 0 in Response Time and Content Length

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cloud, azure-devops, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a question on the Load Test Results in the Tables View of the Load Test Analyzer. 
[image]

Based on this screenshoot, we can see that the response time and content length is 0 even i have fire this request for 10 times.
[image]
I open one of the test log of the request and it show this with the amount of response time and response bytes.
[image]
I have browse the site with browser and this is data get from the debugger tools.

Why the load test report data has different value with inside the test log? how they able calculate and collect the 0 response time and also 0 content length.

Comment: All 10 requests failed. You need to look in the "Details" tab, you can almost see its title at the bottom of the second screenshot. It may be that the transaction table values exclude failed requests. It may also be that the requests were done during the load test warm up period.

Comment: I just test with bing.com, the response time is 0.060 and content length is 42363 in request table. Try to test with bing.com and check the result.

Comment: @AdrianHHH i purposely to create a validation rule to indicate it is failed request, so that i can get the log of all request. My transaction table are totally blank. There's no warm up period used, i have set the test ended with test iteration.

Comment: @starain-MSFT yes. That's why it sometimes work, but sometimes don't. Sometimes it show 0 on the request table. But there's a average response time at Load Test summary but not 0 value

Comment: Setting the requests as failed (in a plugin) may mean their times are not included. To get logs of all test cases see the big paragraph in my answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41239818/546871 then no plugin to set failures is needed.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Even I remove the validation checking and have my results are all passed. It still displaying me as 0 in response time and content length under the request table.

Comment: Does it occur if you just create new method with simple web request? And does it display correctly in web portal?